# number of ways of counting so that A never lags behind B

Tags: combinatorics

Two candidate A and B contested for president-ship  elections. Each of them got 5 votes. The number of ways a counting be done so that at no stage of counting A lags behind B

i think this is an interesting problem as there are too many possible cases .I couldnt proceed much. I know the total number of ways in which counting can be done without restrictions is $\binom{10}{5}$.i tried considering cases but too many of them.My intuition is that it has something to do with  symmetry ie the number of cases in which B lags at each stage=no of cases in which A lags in each stage.Also i know the counting has to start with A (obviously!).Can anyone guide me?

Comment: This is roughly the question posed by [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem), though the classical result generally considers the non-tie case.  The same techniques apply, however.  See also [Dyck Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language).

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @lulu i read the articles you had mentioned.But i dont seem to understand them clearly It is going beyond my head. Is there a simpler method or a more rigorous explanation

Comment: Since $5$ is so small there is no reason not to do it by hand.  Work recursively.  That is, let $F(n)$ be the result if they each have $n$ votes, so you want $F(5)$.  Then $F(1)=1$ and $F(2)=2$ (since you can do $ABAB$ or $AABB$). Now work out $F(3)$, $F(4)$, $F(5)$.